# KVM installation in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, libvirt

I have tried installing KVM according to the guidelines provided on Ubuntu wiki but when I open Virtual Machine Manager it says that,

'Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.'

I have hardware virtulization enabled in my BIOS settings. Here, is a output of **sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok**:

INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module msr not found.

Also, output of **sudo modprobe kvm_intel** is as follows:

modprobe: FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running Ubuntu 14.04 with recent kernel version. But it eventually turned out that KVM works well with Ubuntu kernel only. So I tried using 3.13.0-24-generic which comes by default with Ubuntu 14.04 and this solved my problem. KVM is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 4):

It does look like the installation failed.

What's the output of this command?

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```

I expect no output. If that so, is it [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/kvm) the guide you followed? What was the output of

```
sudo apt-get install kvm qemu
```

Comment: Yes. Command lsmod | grep kvm gives no output. I used this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation. Installation didn't fail I guess. Even right now command gives me this output: "qemu-kvm is already the newest version.
qemu is already the newest version."

Comment: Is it something like kvm works with Ubuntu kernel? I am currently using recent stable kernel version 4.1.

Comment: It works with ubuntu, I am using it with an older kernel version. Sorry if I insist on this, but you're 100% sure VT is enabled on BIOS? :)

Comment: Yes. VT is enabled on BIOS. The solution which I posted works for me. But still I want to know which Ubuntu version and kernel version are you using?

Comment: Ah, then definitely KVM should work. It comes with 3.19. :)

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I get output for lsmod: "kvm                   663552  0"
Is this as it should be?

Comment: you're supposed to have something like
```
kvm_intel <somenumber> 0
kvm <somenumber> 1
```

which shows that kvm is used by 1 other driver (that is kvm_intel). It seems you lack of kvm_intel (or kvm driver for amd or whatever hw you have)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have it installed:
Fedora:

> yum install kvm qemu

Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install kvm qemu

Answer (score 1):

Install using `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm`

You should also check if Virtualization Technology is enabled.
To do this, reboot your system, enter BIOS and enable Intel VTT or Intel VT-d from virtualization options. Save and exit.